# Concatenating lists in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have captured two sets of values by using JSON extractor in JMeter which I want to concatenate. Let me give you an example below for the format which I want to use.

The following are the two sets of captured values:

Set 1: `[V2520 V2522 V2521 V2500 V2500]`

Set 2: `[PL PL PL NP NP]`

So from the above sets, I am looking for the something like the following value, because the body which I have to send in a subsequent call contains the combination of these 2 values:

Answer: `["V2520PL", "V2522PL", "V2521PL", "V2500NP", "V2500NP"]`

Can you please help me how to solve this in JMeter using Groovy?
This is the JSON I have:

```
{ "body": {
"responseObject": [
  {
    "benefitInfo": [
      {
        "procedureCode": "V2520",
        "modifier": "PL",
        "usage": "Dress",
        "authorizationID": null,
        "description": "ContactLensDisposable",
        "id": "96",
        "coPayAmount": "25"
      },
      {
        "procedureCode": "V2522",
        "modifier": "PL",
        "usage": "Dress",
        "authorizationID": null,
        "description": "ContactLensDisposableBifocal",
        "id": "98",
        "coPayAmount": "25"
      },
      {
        "procedureCode": "V2521",
        "modifier": "PL",
        "usage": "Dress",
        "authorizationID": null,
        "description": "ContactLensDisposableToric",
        "id": "97",
        "coPayAmount": "25"
      },
      {
        "procedureCode": "V2500",
        "modifier": "NP",
        "usage": "Dress",
        "authorizationID": null,
        "description": "ContactLens (Non Plan)",
        "id": "89",
        "coPayAmount": "0"
      },
      {
        "procedureCode": "V2500",
        "modifier": "NP",
        "usage": "Dress",
        "authorizationID": null,
        "description": "ContactLensConventional (Non Plan)",
        "id": "157",
        "coPayAmount": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def answer = []
   def benefitInfos = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$..benefitInfo')
   benefitInfos.each { benefitInfo ->
       benefitInfo.each { entry ->
           answer.add(entry.get('procedureCode') + entry.get('modifier'))
       }
   }
   vars.put('answer', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(answer).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. That's it, you will be able to access generated value as `${answer}` where required:

   [image]

References:

- [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to combine them as you collect the values from the JSON when you parse it.

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(text)
def answer = json.body.responseObject[0].benefitInfo.collect { it.procedureCode + it.modifier }

assert answer == ["V2520PL", "V2522PL", "V2521PL", "V2500NP", "V2500NP"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to use `transpose()` and `join()`:

```
def r = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(text).body.responseObject.benefitInfo[0]
def answer = [r.procedureCode, r.modifier].transpose()*.join()

assert answer == ["V2520PL", "V2522PL", "V2521PL", "V2500NP", "V2500NP"]
```